# How to remove the relative distance between the four delayed noisy sine waves and start them from the beginning?

Tags: vhdl

We are trying to generate a noisy sine wave signal, that will be phase shifted three times to generate signals s1,s2,s3 and s4. For that we have created an array sine2 that will hold the noisy sine wave signal, and we will shift it according to our convenience by changing its index.

The problem is why is s1,s2,s3,s4 not starting from the beginning(ie from t=0)? and why is there relative gaps between the signal as visible from the figure. We need to remove that gap, and if posiible start it from t=0. Please help.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;  --try to use this library as much as possible.

entity sine_wave is
 generic ( width : integer :=  4 ); 
port (clk :in  std_logic;
      random_num : out std_logic_vector (width-1 downto 0); 
      data_outa,data_outb,data_outc,data_outd : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)
      );
end sine_wave;

architecture Behavioral of sine_wave is
signal data_out1,rand_temp1,noisy_signal,data_outb1,data_outc1,data_outd1, summation_signal : integer;
signal noisy_signal1,s1,s2,s3,s4 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
signal summation_signal1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0);
signal i : integer :=0;
signal j : integer :=120;
signal k : integer :=40;
signal l : integer :=80;
signal ii,iii: integer :=0 ;
signal jj: integer :=30 ;
signal kk: integer :=60 ;
signal ll: integer :=90 ;
--type memory_type is array (0 to 29) of integer;
type memory_type is array (0 to 359) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
signal sine2 : memory_type;
--ROM for storing the sine values generated by MATLAB.
signal sine : memory_type :=(x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"01",x"01",
x"01",x"01",x"01",x"01",x"02",x"02",x"02",x"02",x"03",x"03",
x"03",x"04",x"04",x"04",x"04",x"05",x"05",x"05",x"05",x"06",
x"06",x"07",x"07",x"08",x"08",x"09",x"09",x"0a",x"0a",x"0b",
x"0b",x"0c",x"0c",x"0d",x"0d",x"0e",x"0e",x"0f",x"0f",x"10",
x"11",x"11",x"12",x"13",x"13",x"14",x"15",x"15",x"16",x"17",
x"18",x"18",x"19",x"1a",x"1b",x"1b",x"1c",x"1d",x"1e",x"1e",
x"1f",x"20",x"21",x"22",x"23",x"23",x"24",x"25",x"26",x"27",
x"28",x"29",x"2a",x"2b",x"2c",x"2d",x"2f",x"2f",x"30",x"31",
x"32",x"34",x"35",x"35",x"36",x"37",x"38",x"39",x"3a",x"3b",
x"3c",x"3c",x"3e",x"3f",x"40",x"41",x"42",x"43",x"44",x"45",
x"46",x"46",x"47",x"48",x"49",x"49",x"4a",x"4b",x"4c",x"4c",
x"4e",x"4f",x"4f",x"50",x"51",x"51",x"52",x"53",x"53",x"54",
x"55",x"55",x"56",x"57",x"57",x"58",x"58",x"59",x"59",x"5a",
x"5a",x"5b",x"5b",x"5c",x"5c",x"5d",x"5d",x"5e",x"5e",x"5f",
x"5f",x"5f",x"60",x"60",x"60",x"61",x"61",x"61",x"61",x"62",
x"62",x"62",x"62",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"64",
x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",
x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"63",
x"63",x"63",x"62",x"62",x"62",x"62",x"61",x"61",x"61",x"60",
x"60",x"60",x"5f",x"5f",x"5f",x"5e",x"5e",x"5d",x"5d",x"5c",
x"5c",x"5b",x"5b",x"5a",x"5a",x"59",x"59",x"58",x"58",x"57",
x"57",x"56",x"55",x"55",x"54",x"54",x"53",x"53",x"52",x"51",
x"51",x"50",x"4f",x"4f",x"4e",x"4d",x"4c",x"4c",x"4b",x"4a",
x"49",x"49",x"48",x"47",x"46",x"46",x"45",x"44",x"44",x"43",
x"42",x"41",x"41",x"40",x"3f",x"3e",x"3d",x"3c",x"3c",x"3b",
x"3a",x"39",x"38",x"37",x"36",x"35",x"35",x"34",x"33",x"32",
x"31",x"30",x"2f",x"2f",x"2e",x"2d",x"2c",x"2b",x"2a",x"29",
x"28",x"28",x"27",x"26",x"25",x"24",x"23",x"23",x"22",x"21",
x"20",x"1f",x"1e",x"1e",x"1d",x"1c",x"1b",x"1b",x"1a",x"19",
x"18",x"18",x"17",x"16",x"15",x"15",x"14",x"13",x"13",x"12",
x"11",x"11",x"10",x"0f",x"0f",x"0e",x"0d",x"0d",x"0c",x"0c",
x"0b",x"0b",x"0a",x"0a",x"09",x"09",x"08",x"08",x"07",x"07",
x"06",x"06",x"05",x"05",x"05",x"04",x"04",x"04",x"03",x"03",
x"03",x"02",x"02",x"02",x"02",x"01",x"01",x"01",x"01",x"01",
x"01",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00");
--hi
begin

process(clk)
variable rand_temp : std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0):=(width-1 => '1',others => '0');
variable temp : std_logic := '0';
begin
  --to check the rising edge of the clock signal
if(rising_edge(clk)) then  

temp := rand_temp(width-1) xor rand_temp(width-2);
rand_temp(width-1 downto 1) := rand_temp(width-2 downto 0);
rand_temp(0) := temp;

--data_out <= sine(i);
i <= i+ 1;
if(i = 359) then
i <= 0;
end if;

j <= j+ 1;
if(j = 359) then
j <= 0;
end if;

k <= k+ 1;
if(k = 359) then
k <= 0;
end if;

l <= l+ 1;
if(l = 359) then
l <= 0;
end if;

data_outa <= sine(i);

data_outb <= sine(j);
data_outc <= sine(k);
data_outd <= sine(l);


random_num <= rand_temp;
rand_temp1<=to_integer(unsigned(rand_temp));
data_out1<=to_integer(unsigned(sine(i)));
noisy_signal<=data_out1+rand_temp1;
noisy_signal1<= std_logic_vector(to_signed(noisy_signal,8));
--data_outb1 <= to_integer(unsigned(sine(j)));
--data_outc1 <= to_integer(unsigned(sine(k)));
--data_outd1 <= to_integer(unsigned(sine(l)));
--summation_signal <= data_outb1+data_outc1+data_outd1+noisy_signal;
--summation_signal1 <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(summation_signal,12));

--for ii in 0 to 359 loop
--   sine2(ii)<=noisy_signal1;
--   s1 <= sine2(ii);   
--  end loop;

sine2(ii)<=noisy_signal1;
     ii <= ii+ 1;
         if(ii = 359) then
         ii <=0;
         end if;

     s1 <= sine2(iii);
     iii <= iii+ 1;
     if(iii = 359) then
     iii <= 0;
     end if;

    s2 <= sine2(jj);
    jj <= jj+ 1;
    if(jj = 359) then
    jj <= 0;
    end if;
     s3 <= sine2(kk);
     kk <= kk+ 1;
     if(kk = 359) then
     kk <= 0;
     end if;
     s4 <= sine2(ll);
     ll <= ll+ 1;
     if(ll = 359) then
     ll <= 0;
     end if;

end if;
--data_outa <= sine(i);

--data_outb <= sine(j);
--data_outc <= sine(k);
--data_outd <= sine(l);

--data_out1<=to_integer(unsigned(sine(i)));
--random_num <= rand_temp;
--rand_temp1<=to_integer(unsigned(rand_temp));
--noisy_signal<=data_out1+rand_temp1;
--noisy_signal1<= std_logic_vector(to_signed(noisy_signal,8));
----data_outb1 <= to_integer(unsigned(sine(j)));
----data_outc1 <= to_integer(unsigned(sine(k)));
----data_outd1 <= to_integer(unsigned(sine(l)));
----summation_signal <= data_outb1+data_outc1+data_outd1+noisy_signal;
----summation_signal1 <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(summation_signal,12));

----for ii in 0 to 359 loop
----     sine2(ii)<=noisy_signal1;
----     s1 <= sine2(ii);   
----    end loop;

end process;



end Behavioral;
```

[image]

Comment: If they all started together then there would be zero phase shift between them.

Comment: I'm not great with VHDL, but a couple of things: some comments would be nice, and you should probably think about how to modularize/refactor your code into functions.

Comment: where's your testbench?

Comment: The delays before valid (non all 'U') data on s1, s2, s3 and S4 appear to be because sine2 isn't fully populated before it's used (e.g. s1 <= sine2(iii);).

Comment: The initial value in the declaration of rand_temp isn't valid VHDL `:= (WIDTH - 1 => '1', others => '0');`. WIDTH is a globally static use positional association instead `:= ('1', others => '0');` See IEEE Std 1076-2008, 9.3.3.3 Array aggregates, para 6, para 7 (aggregate with an others choice may appear) *f) As the expression defining the initial value of a constant or variable object, where that object is declared to be of a fully constrained array subtype* and *In each case, the applicable index constraint is locally static.* An iSIM shortcoming (Vivado 2014.4), possibly fixed since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apparent different starting points are a simulation artifact caused by sine2 not being initialized and different sine wave outputs using different starting points in the sine2 table.  The four generators get valid data at different times. Prior to that sine2 values would be "UUUUUUUU"s.

The idea here is to hold off s1, s2, s3 and s4 outputs until sine2 has been completely loaded once.

There's an added signal to indicate when sine2 has been completely loaded once:

```
signal ll: integer := 90;

signal ii_gate: std_logic := '0';  -- ADDED signal

type memory_type is array (0 to 359) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
signal sine2:  memory_type;
```

Then in the process:

```
        sine2(ii) <= noisy_signal1;

        ii <= ii + 1;
        if ii = 359 then
            ii <= 0;
            ii_gate <= '1';  -- set ii_gate when sine2 has been written once
        end if;

        if ii_gate = '1' then  -- use ii_gate to hold off s1,s2,s3 and s4

            s1 <= sine2(iii);
            iii <= iii + 1;
            if iii = 359 then
                iii <= 0;
            end if;

            s2 <= sine2(jj);
            jj <= jj + 1;
            if jj = 359 then
                jj <= 0;
            end if;

            s3 <= sine2(kk);
            kk <= kk + 1;
            if kk = 359 then
                kk <= 0;
            end if;

            s4 <= sine2(ll);
            ll <= ll + 1;
            if ll = 359 then
                ll <= 0;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;   -- rising_edge(clk)
```

The signal ii_gate holds off output of s1, s2, s3 and s4 until sine2 had been loaded once eliminating 'U' values on sine2 table look ups. You could contemplate the effects of uninitialized sine2 memory on start up in an FPGA.

The modified design specification gives:

[image: sine_wave_tb_fixed.png]

and shows all four waveforms displaying valid data at the same time. Note the phase differences are visible in the waveform.

A testbench for the design:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity sine_wave_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of sine_wave_tb is
    constant WIDTH:     integer :=   4; 
    signal clk:         std_logic := '0';
    signal random_num:  std_logic_vector (WIDTH - 1 downto 0); 
    signal data_outa,
           data_outb,
           data_outc,
           data_outd:   std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
begin
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 50 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if now > 500 us then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;

DUT:
    entity work.sine_wave
        generic map (WIDTH => WIDTH)
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            random_num => random_num,
            data_outa => data_outa,
            data_outb => data_outb,
            data_outc => data_outc,
            data_outd => data_outd
        );
end architecture;
```

I also  commented on your question noting the aggregate for the initial value to rand_temp cannot be represented compliantly to the VHDL standard using an aggregate with a non-locally static index and an others choice.

I changed that as well:

```
begin

    process(clk)
        variable rand_temp:  std_logic_vector(WIDTH - 1 downto 0) 
                    -- := (WIDTH - 1 => '1', others => '0');
                    := ('1', others => '0');
        variable temp:  std_logic :=  '0';
    begin
```

See IEEE Std 1076-2008, 9.3.3.3 Array aggregates, paragraphs 6 and 7 which specify the limitation.

Using positional association sidesteps the issue insuring standard compliance and design specification portability.

If someone reports it as a bug it could be fixed.